# How to make autofill into add/remove field dynamically using jquery?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, autofill

I am doing a program using laravel. I use add/remove field with jquery. The first field grab the data from database to list out the person's name.

```
     <div class="container table-responsive col-lg-10">
          <form method="post" id="dynamic_form">
            <span id="result"></span>
             <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered" id="user_table">
           <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-3">Nama</th>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-2">No Personal</th>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Jabatan</th>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Telefon</th>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Ext</th>
                <td class="text-center col-lg-1">Action</th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>

           </tbody>
           <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
           </tfoot>
       </table>
    </div>  
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

      var count = 1;

      dynamic_field(count);

      function dynamic_field(number)
      {
      html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td><select id="nama" name="nama[]" class="form-control"><option value="">--Pilih--</option><?php foreach($staff as $key => $value):echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.addslashes($value).'</option>'; endforeach; ?></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="no_personal[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="jabatan[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="telefon[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" name="ext[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    if(number > 1)
    {
        html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Batal</button></td></tr>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
    }
    else
    {   
        html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Tambah Pegawai</button></td></tr>';
        $('tbody').html(html);
    }
}

   $(document).on('change', '.nama', function(){
    var staffID = jQuery(this).val();
    if(staffID)
    {
      jQuery.ajax({
          url : 'add_demo/get_staff/'+staffID,
          type : "GET",
          dataType : "json",
          success:function(data)
          {
            console.log(data);
                $('#no_personal').val(data.Nobadan);
                $('#jabatan').val(data.SectionID);
                $('#telefon').val(data.notelttp);
                $('#ext').val(data.ext);   
          }
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $('#no_personal').empty();
      $('#jabatan').empty();
      $('#telefon').empty();
      $('#ext').empty();
    }
  });


 $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
  count++;
  dynamic_field(count);
  });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });

});
</script>
```

I had edited the js code:

```
    function dynamic_field(number)
 {
  html = '<tr>';
     html += '<td><select id="nama_'+ count +'" name="nama[]" class="form-control"><option value="">Pilih</option><?php foreach($pegawai as $key => $value):echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.addslashes($value).'</option>'; endforeach; ?></select></td>';
    html += '<td><input id="nb_'+ count +'" type="text" name="no_badan[]" class="form-control"  value="nb_'+ count +'" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input id="sek_'+ count +'" type="text" name="seksyen[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input id="tel_'+ count +'" type="text" name="telefon[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input id="ext_'+ count +'" type="text" name="ext[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
    if(number > 1)
    {
        html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Batal</button></td></tr>';
        $('tbody').append(html);
    }
    else
    {   
        html += '<td class="text-center"><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Tambah</button></td></tr>';
        $('tbody').html(html);
    }
 }

 $(document).on('change', '.nama_'+ count +'', function(){
    var staffID = jQuery(this).val();
    if(staffID)
    {
      jQuery.ajax({
          url : 'add_demo/get_sta/'+staffID,
          type : "GET",
          dataType : "json",
          success:function(data)
          {
            console.log(data);
                $('#nb_'+ count +'').val(data.Nobadan);
                $('#seksyen').val(data.SectionID);
                $('#telefon').val(data.notelttp);
                $('#ext').val(data.ext);   
          }
      });
    }
    else
    {
      $('#nb_'+ count +'').empty();
      $('#seksyen').empty();
      $('#telefon').empty();
      $('#ext').empty();
    }
  });


  $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
   count++;
   dynamic_field(count);
 });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  });

  });
 </script>
```

When the first field（staff name）selected，the information  about no_personal, jabatan, telefon and ext will be filled automatically into the field. The information grabbed using this ajax url:

```
 url : 'add_demo/get_staff/'+staffID,
```

The controller for that is:

```
$data = staffs::where('staffID', $staffID)
            ->select('staffs.No_pers', 'staffs.JabID', 'staffs.notel', 'staffs.ext')
            ->first();

return json_encode($data);
```

I can list out the staff name in the selection box. But when I selected the staff name, the information is not filled into the fields.

The field had been given an id like this:

```
 html += '<td><input id="nb_'+ count++ +'" type="text" name="no_badan[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
```

How to improvised the code? I tried to put id in the added fields, but it gives error of same id name for added fields.

[image: dom error]

Comment: Why the error appear?

Comment: The same field appears to be 14 fields in the console.

Comment: You also need to add count with your change method as well, like you are passing the value it's selected field. `$('#nb_'+count).val(data.Nobadan);` just like this etc...

Comment: The problem is that, you are making the fields dynamic, but you are using the dropdown same for all, you need to make it dynamic too, so that when you are calling the ajax, it will be dynamic for every appended row. With this procedure you will be able to put values to dynamic fields as well. like I have done in above comment.

Comment: And above you have used an `id="nama"` for the `nama` but in change method you are accessing it with `class` or `.`

Comment: I had edited the variable name as suggested but the 14 error still appear

Comment: Have you inspect element and seen the select or other fields, whether they are properly incrementing or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206834/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-joun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the easiest way to create a component like this. Please look at my given below snippets code.

```js
$(document).on('click','.add',function(){
        var clonned = $(this).parents('.clonable:last-child').clone();
        parentId = clonned.attr('parentId');
        clonned.attr('parentId',parseInt(parentId)+1);
        clonned.find('input[type="text"]').each(function(){
            return $(this).val('');
        })
        $('.clonable').parents('tbody').append(clonned);
    });
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
        $(this).parents('.clonable').remove();
    });

   $(document).on('change', '.nama', function(){
        var staffID = $(this).val();
        var parentId = $(this).parents('.clonable').attr('parentId');
        if(staffID){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : 'add_demo/get_staff/'+staffID,
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "json",
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="no_personal[]"]').val(data.Nobadan);
                    $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="jabatan[]"]').val(data.SectionID);
                    $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="telefon[]"]').val(data.notelttp);
                    $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="ext[]"]').val(data.ext);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="no_personal[]"]').val('');
            $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="jabatan[]"]').val('');
            $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="telefon[]"]').val('');
            $('tr[parentId="'+parentId+'"] input[name="ext[]"]').val('');
        }
    });
```

```css
.clonable .add{
  display: none;
}
.clonable:last-child .add{
  display: inline-block !important;  
}
.clonable:only-child .remove{
  display: none !important;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container table-responsive col-lg-10">
        <form method="post" id="dynamic_form">
            <span id="result"></span>
            <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered" id="user_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-3">Nama</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-2">No Personal</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-1">Jabatan</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-1">Telefon</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-1">Ext</th>
                        <th class="text-center col-lg-1">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="clonable" parentId="1">
                        <td>
                            <select id="nama" name="nama[]" class="form-control nama">
                                <option value="">--Pilih--</option>
                                <?php foreach($staff as $key => $value){?>
                                    <option value="<?=$key?>"><?=addslashes($value)?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="no_personal" name="no_personal[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="jabatan" name="jabatan[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="telefon" name="telefon[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="ext" name="ext[]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td class="text-center">
                            <button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Batal</button>
                            <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success add">Tambah Pegawai</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="6" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion:

> Please check the **id**, its not unique.

Use the proper count to increment the ID

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The id is unique but the console shows some repetition ( I don't know why). I had searched for weeks and using class instead of id.